# Undefined Index when querying inside a while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

My problem: When the second while loop runs I get an Undefined Index: first and last. 
I get the right number of first and last Notice messages in each loop. So everything is good except it wont give me the actual names.

I am new to this so I am sure I am just not clear on some rules or something.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM practice WHERE tid='$tid' ORDER BY date";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<br> ". $row["date"]. " @ " . $row["time"] ." ". $row["pid"] ." 
        <form action='includes/joinpractice.inc.php' method='POST'> 
        <input type='hidden' name='pid' value='". $row["pid"] ."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='". $id ."'>
        <button type='submit'>Join Practice</button>
        </form> <br>";

    $sql = "SELECT user.first, user.last 
            FROM user 
                INNER JOIN practice_part ON user.id=practice_part.uid
            WHERE pid = '". $row["pid"] ."'";

    $innerresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while ($innerrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($innerresult)) {
        echo "<br> ". $row["first"] ." ". $row["last"] .""; 
    }
}
```

I have tried using
. $row["user.first"] ." ". $row["user.last"] . but this made no difference. Thank you for any input.

Comment: You are pointing to the former result, your code should be:

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change this:

```
echo "<br> ". $row["first"] ." ". $row["last"] ."";
```

for this:

```
echo "<br> ". $innerrow["first"] ." ". $innerrow["last"] ."";
```